# can a single force rotate an object. not a torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

Can a single force (not a torque) rotate an object?  How can the bar below fall given the force $\mathbf F$?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a force strikes an object along a line that does not go through the center of mass, the result is both a translation and a rotation of the object.

Whether you consider such a force a "torque" is a matter of definition. I would normally say that it is - but if you consider it "just a force" then the answer to your question as posed is "yes".

At any rate - if you apply an impulse $F\Delta t$ to the rod in your picture at an orthogonal distance $r$ from the center of mass, you will impart an angular momentum $F\Delta t \cdot r$ to the rod.

Answer (score 0):

A single point force not acting at the COG, will always provide a torque but this torque will be accompanied by a net linear force as well since there is no opposing force. So, the net motion will be a combination of rotational and linear motion.

Notice that when we talk about torque, we talk about angular velocity and hence give up our knowledge of centre of rotation which is the point having zero ‘linear’ velocity. This means the torque/couple is not applied to/about any particular point but to a rigid body as a whole causing the same angular velocity/acceleration of every point of the rigid body. To get the information about the point of rotation we need to go back to our frame of reference and check which point is constrained/ fixed to have zero linear velocity.